# Cant get live data to update in listview Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, parse-platform, windows-phone-8.1

For some reason this proecedure is not returning live data from parse.com it is only bringing back the correct data when i exit the application i need to retrieve the data from parse so for example if someone changes the data in parse end its reflected in the app

```
 public async Task<List<MagicLists>> GetListsAync()
    {
        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("lists");
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> result = new List<ParseObject>();
        try
        {
            result = await query.FindAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

        var listItems = new List<MagicLists>();
        foreach (var listItemParseObject in result)
        {
            var listItem = await MagicLists.CreateFromParseObject(listItemParseObject);
            listItems.Add(listItem);
        }
        return listItems;
 }
```

My list is as follows and I dont understand why its not just getting

```
using Parse;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace MagicLists.DataModel
{
public class MagicLists :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
            public MagicLists()
        {

        }
        public MagicLists(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String imagePath, String description, String content,string type)
        {
            this.UniqueId = uniqueId;
            this.Title = title;
            this.Subtitle = subtitle;
            this.Description = description;
            this.ImagePath = imagePath;
            this.Content = content;
            this.Type = type;
        }


        public MagicLists(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String imagePath, String description, String content, bool unread,Int32 status)
        {
            UniqueId = uniqueId;
            Title = title;
            Subtitle = subtitle;
            Description = description;
            ImagePath = imagePath;
            Content = content;
            Unread = unread;
            Status = status;
        }


        private bool _unread;

        private string _title;
        public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }

            set
            {
                _title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
        public string Subtitle { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; private set; }
        public string Content { get; private set; }
        public int Status { get; private set; }
        public string Type { get; private set; }

        public string ViewToUse { get; private set; }
        public bool Unread
        {
            get { return _unread; }
            set
            {
                _unread = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Unread");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        public static async Task<MagicLists> CreateFromParseObject(ParseObject parseObject)
        {
            return await Task.Run<MagicLists>(() =>
            {
                var mlist = new MagicLists();

                mlist.Title = parseObject.ObjectId;
                if (parseObject.ContainsKey("name"))
                {
                    mlist.Title = (string)parseObject["name"];
                }


                if (parseObject.ContainsKey("description"))
                {
                    mlist.Description = (string)parseObject["description"];
                }
                if (parseObject.ContainsKey("image"))
                {
                    mlist.ImagePath = (string)parseObject["image"];
                }


                if (parseObject.ContainsKey("type"))
                {
                    string mtype = (string)parseObject["type"];

                    if (mtype == "N")

                    {
                        mlist.Type = "Notes";
                        mlist.ViewToUse = "Notes.Xaml";
                    }
                }
                return mlist;
            });
        }
    }

}
```

On my listview refresh i am doing the following

```
    private async Task LstView_OnPullToRefreshRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstView.ItemsSource = null;
        List<DataModel.MagicLists> mLists;
        mLists = await _db.GetListsAync();

        lstView.ItemsSource = mLists;
    }
```

But its just bringing back the old data not the adjusted data in parse ?.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case others find this this is indead a bug in parse sdk for windows phone 8.1 and has been fixed for the next release as they have said here in my original bug tracker.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1485207861770147/